# How can I get only one column value from html table?

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

I have a html table that shows a list of users ID, Name and E-mail. When my user clicks in any row, I get the id number of that row and send to my backend. So, I did this:

```
//Making the table
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
  trs[i].onclick = clickHandler;   
}
```

Function that handles the click:

```
function clickHandler(event) {
  var numb = this.innerText.match(/\d/g);
  numb = numb.join("");
  window.location.replace("chooseParticipant.php?id="+numb);  
}
```

Table Example:

```
<div id="table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Test User</td>
            <td>testuser123@example.com</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

What happens then? If an user have numbers in their e-mail, the "numb" variable gets these numbers too. I don't know how to filter only the id number. Did someone have any ideas?

Comment: If you added an example `tr` we could maybe, only maybe, help you.

Comment: I did it now. Do you think that needs more info?

Comment: First of all that HTML is invalid. Then, why do you select the whole tr instead of only and exactly the element you need?

Comment: If I only add the click handler event to the TD element, my user will need to click in the number to trigger the function. I really needed the user to click in any point of the row. And why the HTML is invalid? I don't understand.

Comment: The HTML is invalid because you have `td` without any `tr` around them (in tbody).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a class to you  tag.
Something like below:-

```
    <td class="id">7</td>
```

And in the javascript code you could fetch all the elements with class "id".
And then perform your click handler on each one.

```
    var trs = document.getElementsByClassName('id');
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot.

Comment: `id` seems like a really bad name for a class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet which use `data-*` attribute

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  var trs = document.querySelectorAll('#table tbody tr');
  var repeater = Array.prototype.slice;
  repeater.call(trs).forEach(function(tr) {
    tr.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var data = tr.querySelector('td[data-id]').dataset;
      console.log('id=', data.id);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
tbody {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-id="7">7</td>
        <td>Test User 1</td>
        <td>testuser1231@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-id="8">8</td>
        <td>Test User 2</td>
        <td>testuser1232@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-id="9">9</td>
        <td>Test User 3</td>
        <td>testuser1233@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```